# Explain about Vector() in java

Tags: java

```
String e=empId.getText();
 DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
 Connection c = DBconnect.connect();
Statement s=c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT empId, name from employee where empId = '"+e+"')";
        while(rs.next()){
            Vector v=new Vector();
            v.add(rs.getString("empId"));
            v.add((rs.getString("name")));
            dtm.addRow(v);
        }
```

I did this coding but i actually don't know what is happening here, form this i add search result values of table employee into my jTable what is the meaning of using Vector here,can some one give me a clear explanation please

Comment: You coded and explained your self to us. What else you didn't get here.

Comment: Did you try googling Vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API for `DefaultTableModel` has a method `addRow(Vector rowData)`. You are using that method, so you need a new `Vector` object for each row of data that you want to add. That's why each time through the `while` loop (which seems to be misspelled as `While` in your posted code) allocates a new `Vector` object and then populates it with two items from the row. The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.util.Vector)) explain how the `addRow` method works. Note that there's also an `addRow(Object[] rowData)` method, so your loop could have instead been:

```
while(rs.next()){
    Object[] rowData = {
         rs.getString("empId"),
         rs.getString("name")
    };
    dtm.addRow(rowData);
}
```

Comment: Which could be collapsed to `dtm.addRow(new Object[] { rs.getString("empId"), rs.getString("name") });`